# yum dependency conflict in ImageMagick update

Tags: centos6, yum, dependencies, imagemagick

I am running a Lamp server on `CentOS release 6.6 (Final)` with php5.5:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.17 (cli) (built: Sep 20 2014 17:12:00)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

When I run `yum update` I get this dependency error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libwebp.x86_64 0:0.3.1-2.el6.remi will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.4()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.8.9.7-4.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package libwebp.x86_64 0:0.4.3-3.el6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.8.9.7-4.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Requires: libwebp.so.4()(64bit)
           Removing: libwebp-0.3.1-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               libwebp.so.4()(64bit)
           Updated By: libwebp-0.4.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

My *vague* understanding of this is that the ImageMagick update requires `libwebp.so.4`, but I have `libwebp-0.3.1-2.el6.remi.x86_64` from the `@remi` rpm but this has since been updated to `libwebp-0.4.3-3.el6.x86_64` from the `epel` rpm.

Is that correct? If not what does the above output mean?

And more importantly how might I fix this?

Comment: I have tried: `yum clean all`, `yum install libwebp` and `yum update --disablerepo=remi`. The latter of these two both resulted in the same conflict error as above.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I figured out the answer via [this post](http://forum.remirepo.net/viewtopic.php?pid=7970#p7970) on the forum for the 'Remi' repo.

The `ImageMagick-last-libs` package was outdated. I don't understand why it wasn't being update with the `yum update` command, but this command fixed the problem, and both `ImageMagick` and `libwebp` were updated:

```
yum --disablerepo="webtatic" --enablerepo="remi" install ImageMagick-last-libs-6.9.1.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```